# Dark theme in xampp-control windows 10 pro

Tags: xampp, controls

Can someone tell me if there is any way to see the Xampp control, in dark mode?
Does it look like this.
[image]

But will there be a dark mode theme?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to add black or dark mode in xammp control panel.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33027786)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).